# how to put multiple grouped && , || conditions using if else

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to check conditions with && || groupping it means if one group stisfy then execute the first condition otherwise second and so on so i'll do that with the help of (if else) kindly give me an example

Description:-i have a select box with multiple options so diffrent diffrent div will remain open if the selected option value exists in the session.

```
<div id="bizseg" class="col-sm-4" <?php    if(isset($_SESSION['constitution'])){  if($_SESSION['constitution']=="Individual" && $_SESSION['myprof']=="Self Employed Businessman") {?> style="display:block;" <?php  }else { ?> style="display:none;" <?php }} ?>  style="display:none;">
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: What a terrible mess. :(

Answer (score 0):

Shrbham please read what you posted why 2 if statements???
if it is all tests for true just && them here is the code and formated so it can be read but in HTML output will be 1 line

```
<div id="bizseg" class="col-sm-4" <?php    
    if(
        isset($_SESSION['constitution']) &&
        $_SESSION['constitution'] == $variable &&
        $_SESSION['myprof'] == $variable2 ) {
?> style="display:block;" <?php 
}else { 
?> style="display:none;" <?php } ?>
```

If's are quite simple true or false

```
$var1 = "test";
$var2 = "test";
$var3 = "test2";

//so 
$result = $var1 == $var2; // true
$result = $var2 == $var3; // false
//(false)            (true)           // false and anything == false
if($var2 == $var3 && $var1 == $var2); // false
// (false)           (true)           // true or anything == true 
if($var2 == $var3 || $var1 == $var2); // true

if( ($var2 == $var3 || $var1 == $var2) && $var1 == $val3 ) // false
//  ((false)        || (true))         && (false) ==
//  (true)                             && (false) 
//following rules above and false = false;
```

As "@Lightness Races in Orbit" has said in comments this sort of procedural code is not liked

you can do it as

```
<?php    
    if(
        isset($_SESSION['constitution']) &&
        $_SESSION['constitution'] == $variable &&
        $_SESSION['myprof'] == $variable2 ) 
    {
        $result = 'style="display:block;"'; 
    }else {
        $result = 'style="display:none;"';
    }
?>
<div id="bizseg" class="col-sm-4" <?php echo $result ?>
```

Comment: Please please please please please please don't interpolate HTML and PHP like this.

Comment: This is the way the Question was asked i'm answer the question and if your using procedural PHP this is the way it should be done just coz us pro's know how to use Classes and MVC frameworks / Design patterns i would agree with your but this appears to be a beginner learning to program not gonna baffle the crap out of them

Comment: @Sam go be a kid elsewhere please Grown ups are talking.

Comment: @MartinBarker: First of all, calm down and behave properly please. You're being very unprofessional. Secondly, no, I am not promoting a "MVC framework" or any classes ... just generate your HTML in a sane way without "baffling" interpolation that's very hard to read. Why not assign to a variable `$display_style` inside a standalone conditional, then build the `<div>` tag with just `style="display: $display_style"`? Isn't that much clearer?

Comment: Please read my edit also this is personal preference i can cope with both but i did edit and show the way you prefer